# resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material not found

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am trying to write a Hello World program for android. This is my first experience of Java. Gradle is not running properly, and whenever I try to rerun it, it comes up with 24 error messages:

```
resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material not found
```

and then lots of attributes of android:style/TextAppearance.Material which are also not found. I have tried searching online for how to put something in styles.xml to fix this, but can't find anything useful.

Comment: could you add your build.gradle(Module:app)

Comment: Which Theme you are using in manifest ?

Comment: As I say, I am new to android&java. I don't know what build.gradle(module:app) is, although if it means to rebuild or clean, this  is what caused the errors.

Comment: After <application in the manifest, there is the line android:theme="@style/AppTheme", and inside <activity, there is the line android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change you theme to an Android Support Library's material design theme. 
Don't forget to include the Support Library as well.

Manifest:

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Gradle Build file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
}
```

I would also recommend to you that you read the Styles and Themes documentation. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

Comment: Same problem when I change it.

Comment: the website looks helpful

Comment: Have you added the Support Libraries to your project? I have added that part to my awnser.

Comment: Support library?

Comment: For material design themed apps you can either use a sdk level of min 21(Android 5.0) or the support lib. Read this post here. https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was this:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'androidx.annotation', module: 'annotation'
    compile.exclude group: 'androidx.core', module: 'core'
}
```

had to comment this block out and it worked.