# android resource linking failed whenever i try to build

Tags: java, android

whenever i try to build it gives me this error of android resource linking failed.am new to android development

```
 Android resource linking failed
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body1 not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body2 not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Button not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Caption not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display1 not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display2 not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display3 not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display4 not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Inverse not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Menu not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that SDK version MUST match the support library.

if your Build.gradle like this means

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion should be

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3
```

for more details refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642177/gradle-build-resource-androidstyle-textappearance-material-not-found)

Comment: where i find compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion

Comment: i am new to android so please be more specific and explain more please